# Syntax highlighting is not working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

Syntax highlighting does not work when adding code blocks (Like StackOverflow)
See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7555/syntaxhighlighter-in-blogger-interpreting-br-literally-despite-html-encoding/7558#7558) for an example.

It works here in meta though -@phwd

Comment: Works:  SO, MSO, MWA, PW, MPW, 
Doesn't work:  WA, FC, MFC, A, MA, PR, MPR

Comment: @rchern: But why?

Comment: I don't know.  Seems like something the team will need to look at.  I was just trying to provide further detail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is explicitly disabled. It should be disabled on meta as well.

We don't feel code highlighting is needed on web apps -- preformatted text is all that is intended, and auto-syntax would be a negative, like so:

```
this is a table

item1   item2
-----   -----
3       a
4       b
5       c
```

Comment: That makes sense, but perhaps there could be special cases? For instance if a preformatted text block starts with a shebang. I'm personally interested as I'm active on askubuntu. While I can imagine many times where auto-syntax would be a negative there, there is also the need to post scripts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working in meta.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class SimpleFlash extends MovieClip {
    public function SimpleFlash() {

    }
}

dp.SyntaxHighlighter.BloggerMode();
dp.SyntaxHighlighter.HighlightAll('code');
```

Comment: It doesn't now.