# Enable tagged syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, markdown, formatting

Syntax highlighting has been [disabled here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/689/syntax-highlighting-is-not-working) 2010 because:

> We don't feel code highlighting is needed on web apps -- preformatted text is all that is intended, and auto-syntax would be a negative […]

But nowadays many answers include code: [HTML](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/40018/3949), [CSS](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45426/3949) or [Scripts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/4281/3949). Especially for users who are not very familiar with code, syntax highlighting would make these code snippets more readable.

My request: Turn highlighting on at least when there is a [language tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/145551). This should be read by the parser as a strong need.

Comment: +1, makes it way more attractive !!

Comment: Heh, first example migrated

Comment: @JohnC Thanks, fixed. :)