# How much support does it take for a feature request to be implemented?

Tags: support, tags

This feature request has been implemented:

[Make all recommendation questions out of scope and off topic, regardless of research](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2595/make-all-recommendation-questions-out-of-scope-and-off-topic-regardless-of-rese)

this not:

[Enable tagged syntax highlighting](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/enable-tagged-syntax-highlighting)

Both stand at net +10 *at present* (I have no idea of their votes at the time the former was implemented).

What does it take to have a feature request accepted as meeting general approval?

(The above two look rather the wrong way round, given the latter is without dissent and the former was not unanimous.)

Comment: I'm not sure they're a fair comparison. The first is a policy question that the community has implemented. The second is a configuration change that only Stack Exchange can implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to depend on whether or not any change can be achieved by our mods independently:

YES:

A clear majority in favour - likely a fast implementation.

NO:

Makes no difference what the community view is - never.